# Custom menu command in .mc.menu (Midnight Commander)

Tags: menu

What's wrong with this custom defined command?

```
#   Resize an image using convert
+ f \.jpg$ | f \.JPG$
R   Resize image to fit within 800 pixel bounding square
    size=800
    convert "%f" -resize ${size}x${size} "%b-${size}.%x"
```

When I press `F2` I get:

> Error: No suitable entries found in .mc.menu

Answer (score 2):

After some try and error, I got to a conclusion that what I needed was:

```
shell_patterns=0
```

defined at the top of `.mc.menu` file.

Here is some brief explanation:

> "..Pattern is either a shell pattern (i.e., wildcards) or a regular expression according to the global setting configured in the Options/Configuration dialog. This setting can be overridden by adding shell_patterns=0 as the first line of the menu file. A value of 1 forces use of shell patterns, while a value of 0 forces regular expressions instead."